# Remote ssh command sent by python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, process

Trying to figure out how to send an ssh command.  This works via cli:

```
ssh -i /path/myKey.pem centos@myServer.com lsb_release -a
```

But fails when I set up the command like this:

```
cmd = ['ssh', '-i', '/path/myKey.pem', 'centos@myServer.com', 'lsb_release', '-a']): 
p =  Popen( cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE )
        ( output, errStr ) = p.communicate()
```

I get this back with error number 255:

```
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
       #Snip other usage
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Try to make the remote command (last two items) a single one. If they get quoted as two, `ssh` might not get it.

Comment: Drop `shell=True`; you've already done the hard work of (correctly) assembling a list containing the command name and its arguments. There's nothing for the shell to do.

Comment: @KlausD. I tried 3 forms for the last two arguments.  Single, Single with quotes and split out as separate elements.  None solved the problem.

Comment: @chepner I had also tried without the shell=True and that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `shell=True` with a list, you are running the equivalent of

```
sh -c ssh -i /path/myKey.pem centos@myServer.com lsb_release -a
```

which is *not* what you want; it runs `ssh`, but it uses `-i` as the value of `$0`, not the first argument to `ssh`. This makes `/path/myKey.pem` look like the address of the host you want to connect to.

Just drop `shell=True`.

```
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

---

Though not a problem here, Klaus D.'s suggestion to pass `lsb_release -a` as a single argument is a good idea in general. `ssh` has to join them into a single string in order to pass to `sh -c` on the remote end; may as well do it yourself to make sure it's done correctly.

```
cmd = ['ssh', '-i', '/path/myKey.pem', 'centos@myServer.com', 'lsb_release -a']
```

Comment: OK that is wacky.  It was fixed by the removal of the shell. I thought I had tested that but forgot the order of parameters on my function call (simplified my code for this question).  I would expect the exact same command to be run (shell or not).  I understand the outcome but I do not understand your statement (but it uses -i as the value of $0).  Would be great for this class to have debugging so we could see the actual output.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: The single argument following `-c` is the command to run. The next argument tells the resulting `exec` what name to use for that command, and *then* the arguments to the command are listed. You *could* use something like `Popen(['ssh', 'ssh', '-i', ...], shell=True)` so that you run `sh -c ssh ssh -i ...`, but I think there's little reason to do that.

Comment: (The operating system distinguishes between the name of a file that is executed to run a command, and the name that the resulting process uses to identify it self. By default, that is the file name, but that can be modified in a way specific to each method of starting the process.)